# The best overloaded method match for 'double.TryParse(string, out double)' has some invalid argument

Tags: excel, winforms

I have a excel file which have diff values for diff columns. Now I just collect data from my code :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp1 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook1 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtcd.Text);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook1.Worksheets[1];
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rangeSelection1 = worksheet1.Columns[1];
                int breakCount1 = 0;
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in rangeSelection1.Rows)
                {
                    if (breakCount1 > 20)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (row.Row > 9)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)row.Cells[3, 1];
                        if (cell.Value2 != null)
                        {
                            breakCount1 = 0;
                            string Treadcode = cell.Value2;
                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range NetBalance = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)row.Cells[3, 8];
                            double netbalance = 0.0;
                            try
                            {
                                netbalance = double.TryParse(NetBalance.Value2, out netbalance);
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                netbalance = 0.0;
                            }
                            ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Add(Treadcode,netbalance);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            breakCount1++;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

here is my excel screen :

[image]

here I can't get NetBalance column data. I don't understand what's going wrong here...

Comment: I do the changes u answer. but no success I got this kind of message 'Dear JANVI HIRENKUMAR THAKKAR Your BSE Trade Position:  Code QUICKHEAL Sell 466 @ 166.58  Ledger balance is : . (Aadinath)'  Ledger balance still no value

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks hirenkumar I just solved the issues you save my day